# Numpy multidimensional transpose not giving expected result

Tags: numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have an array with dimensions (2, 3, 4, 5).

When I do `np.transpose(a, (0, 3, 2, 1))` I get back the expected result with shape (2, 5, 4, 3).

But when I do `np.transpose(a, (0, 3, 1, 2))`, I expect to get a result with shape (2, 4, 5, 3) but instead I get a shape of (2, 5, 3, 4)...

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimensions:

0: 2

1: 3

2: 4

3: 5

first transpose (0,3,2,1) -> dims=[2,5,4,3]

Second transpose (0,3,1,2) -> dims=[2,5,3,4]

What's happening is that numpy is doing it's job, you're just feeding wrong shape, what you want is `np.transpose(a, (0, 2, 3, 1))`